# can not find sr_robot_msgs package

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Straight dump of `apt` output:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-sr-robot-msgs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-sr-robot-msgs
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/321749/can-not-find-sr_robot_msgs-package./) by [Jonyu](https://answers.ros.org/users/38590/jonyu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2019-04-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This package has not been released into Kinetic. That is why you cannot install it using `apt`.

See [wiki/sr_robot_msgs](http://wiki.ros.org/sr_robot_msgs) (notice no version button for Kinetic, only Indigo) and [status_page/ros_kinetic_default.html?q=sr_robot_msgs](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_kinetic_default.html?q=sr_robot_msgs).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jonyu](https://answers.ros.org/users/38590/jonyu/) on 2019-04-24**:
thank you.